# How to access list of a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I have the following model;

```
 public class Object
{


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Type { get; set; }
}
```

and i create a view model;

```
public class PlanBaseTypedObjects
{

    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Object> ObjectDetails { get; set; }
}
```

in my controller i did grouping as follows;

```
var model = model1.GroupBy(t => t.Type).Select(g => new PlanBaseTypedObjects
        {
           Id = g.Key,
           ObjectDetails = g
        });
```

How can i get the number of records that belong to a particular "Type"??
for an example for type 1 how many records under ObjectDetails??

and can i access the "objectDetails" directly??
for an example if i want to know the "Name" of Id=3 of Type 2.how can i get it??

Comment: MSDN info on group by: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate on the grouping result to find the count for each one.

```
foreach(var group in model)
{
    int groupCount = group.ObjectDetails.Count();
}
```

If you want to access the items in ObjectDetails you need another foreach:

```
foreach(var group in model
{
    int groupCount = group.ObjectDetails.Count();
    foreach(var item in group.ObjectDetails))
    {
        //do something with item
    }
}
```